# Why can't Mephisto drop super rare unique items?

Tags: diablo-ii

I want to find very rare unique items like "Griffon's Eye", "Death Fathom", "Crown Of Ages", "Immortal King's Soul Cage", etc.
As far as I understand the drop algorithm in Diablo 2, it basically just depends on the Monster Level that allows the item to have the same item level to match the highest quality level of any unique item (Quality Level 87) and the treasure class.

Since Mephisto is level 87 he should be able to drop anything in the game (especially because he is an Act Boss). But he never drops items like Dimensional Shard → Deaths Fathom, Unearthed Wand → Deaths Web, Diadem → Griffons Eye, etc. Even though he is, as I said, level 87 and could theoretically drop a Sacred Armor [qlvl 85], Diadem [qlvl 85] or an Unearthed Wand [qlvl 86]. So that must mean that those mentioned base items are not in his Treasure Class, and he can't drop those base items.

**Is it true Mephisto cannot drop those items?**
If so, is there something else at play here besides TCs and Monster Level vs Quality Level?

(I took the mentioned quality levels from [this Diablo Wikis page](https://diablo2.diablowiki.net/TC_1.10).)

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/64621/144891 has a good explanation about drops mechanics

Comment: I don't undestand why the question has been flagged to Close as off-topic. This is not about game development, but It about game mechanics as I see it, and playing to max loot drops is a perfectly valid gaming motivation/strategy.

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/64621/4182 should be closed instead being too-broad in potential answer.

Comment: The way the question is currently worded, they are asking for a reason why something works the way it does - not mechanically, but whether the developers did something for a specific reason. That's definitely off-topic. Asking about mechanics. or whether a boss drops a certain item, is on-topic. As it is, this question contains both elements. It would be too large of an edit for anyone than the original author to make.

Comment: @arghtype My question is why mephisto can't drop certain items. The rule of thumb as I understand is that if a monster has a high enough level it can drop the item. Diablo has a monster level of 94 and baal of 99. They can drop everything. Nihlatak has mlvl 95 and can drop anything aswell. Why can't Mephisto drop anything? This is the core of the question...

Comment: @IvoCoumans I made an edit to the question explaining my thought process. The main question is absolutely not off topic. It is enough for me if you answer the main question. My secondary question is only off topic if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for besides "because that's the way it works"? What problem are you trying to solve? This looks like an X Y problem to me

Comment: @Wrigglenite I try to understand the drop system and mephisto strikes me as an extreme exception to everything else in the game.

Comment: This question looks good to me. It's about understanding the mechanics of monster level and treasure classes and how they don't always add up 1:1 - This knowledge is very needed in Diablo 2 as they don't display this information in game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hell Mephisto's monster level and treasure are completely different. His monster level is 87, but he doesn't drop anything from TC 81, 84, and 87.

Hell Meph drops up to TC78, while NM Meph drops up to TC54.

Atma's drop calc is obsolete. Use this one: http://mfb.bplaced.net/dropcalc/dropcalc.php?lang=en&patch=113&mode=lod&interface=default&window=true It is mostly correct, just not for duriel, countess and some super unique monsters.

You can see when you select Special Monster -> Mephisto -> Hell that his monster level and TC are different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any way to see / guess the TC of a monster or is it something you have to know. Do you know other instances where let's say some random monster type (like devilkin for example) in an 85 area has a way lower TC than the others?

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer I haven't found any list of the TC's of monsters, but I also haven't looked that hard. I usually look up the item itself and then find which table it is in and then look up the enemies that fall under the table. I've never gone the other way.

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer I think The Countess has a weird drop table because she drops runes and Duriel has been updated since 1.13

Comment: The countess is a whole different topic for itself since her special runedrop conflicts with her regular monster drop. Duriel is quite interesting though. He has an even higher level than Mephisto: Monster Level 88 and can't drop those TC87 items either.

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer Yay my memory isn't totally busted as I'm getting older! Yeah bosses are just weird and the game rewards you for going into side areas more than boss rushing for MF